# How can I use a NSMutablearray from one class, in another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a model that I want to hold some data that I need to be able to access in two other classes.
I've tried logging my array both before and after trying to add `self` to it, but it's null both before and after. I've tried everything that I could think of, plus a ton of googling, but I cannot get this to work.
Here is my model that I create to store some data to:

// CCModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface CCModel : NSObject
// this is the array that I want to store my SKLetterNodes in
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* selectedLetters;
@end
```

// CCModel.m

```
#import "CCModel.h"

@implementation CCModel
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // not really to sure if this is the right approach to init the array that I'm going to need
        self.selectedLetters = [NSMutableArray init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Here's the class that I'm trying to access the NSMutableArray from

// SKLetterNode.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "CCModel.h"

@class SKLetterNode;

@protocol LetterDragDelegateProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)letterNode:(SKLetterNode*)letterNode didDragToPoint:(CGPoint)pt;
@end

@protocol LetterWasTouchedDelegateProtocol <NSObject>
-(void) touchedPoint:(CGPoint)touchedPoint;
@end

@interface SKLetterNode : SKSpriteNode
// Here is where I'm creating a property to access my model's NSMutableArray
@property(strong, nonatomic) CCModel* model;

....
@end
```

// SKLetterNode.m - I'll just include the relevant method since everything else is working in this class

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (!self.isSelected) {

        SKLetterNode* lastLetter = [self.model.selectedLetters lastObject];

        if (lastLetter.bottomOrTop != self.bottomOrTop || self.model.selectedLetters.count == 0) {

            CGSize expandSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width * expandFactor, self.size.height * expandFactor);

            SKAction* sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"button.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
            [self runAction:sound];

            self.isSelected = YES;
            self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:expandSize];
            self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
            self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;

            if (!self.model.selectedLetters) {
                // Here is where I'm trying to init my array by adding an object
                [self.model.selectedLetters arrayByAddingObject:self];
            } else {
                // The array must already be initialized, so add the object
                [self.model.selectedLetters addObject:self];
            }


        }

    }
}
```

As you can see in the if `(!self.model.selectedLetters)` block I'm trying to init the array by adding the object `self` if the array is not initialized. Else, I add the object. I'm trying my hand at objective-c and still new to the language so I'm sure there is just something simple about this process that I don't quit understand.

Comment: Where are you instantiating `model`?  `!self.model.selectedLetters` will return `true` if you don't instantiate `model`, regardless of whether or not `selectedLetters` has been initialized, and if `model` isn't instantiated, you can't initialize a `property` of `model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other 2 posters pointed out 2 problems with your code. (not instantiating a CCModel  object, and calling [NSMutableArray init] instead of [[NSMutableArray alloc] init].

A third problem with your code is that this line:

```
[self.model.selectedLetters arrayByAddingObject:self];
```

Doesn't make sense. That line of code creates a new immutable array, which you then drop on the floor. After you fix the other 2 problems, you want to use code like this

```
[self.model.selectedLetters addObject: self];
```

And do you really want to add "self" to the array? (An SKLetterNode object)

Comment: My thoughts are that I need to store all selected(touched) SkLetterNodes, which are really just SKSpriteNodes, in the array so that each time touchesMoved is called, I can iterate through the array and perform position changes on all of the SKLetterNodes that are stored in the selectedLetter array. I also need to check each time touchesBegan is called, that the last Item in the array resides in the opposite row of where the touch occurred. Basically I have two rows of letters and when a letter is dragged, I want all of the selected, parallel letters to also move.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.selectedLetters = [NSMutableArray init];
```

Should be:

```
self.selectedLetters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And you need to `alloc init` your `CCModel` somewhere in your `SKLetterNode` class too.  If you don't, the `alloc init` on `selectedLetters` will never be called, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use MVC, you should not put view objects in your model. Have a separate model object representing your data model.

Also MVC related, you should not refer to your model from the view. Use your controller (perhaps the scene in a SK app) to connect the model to the view.

Memory management: If I'm correct in assuming that "model" is something that every view is sharing and is created outside the view: The model is retaining the view, and the view is retaining the model. This will leak like a sieve. The connection shouldn't exist at all, but if you wish to keep it, the connection from the view to the model should be weak:

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) CCModel* model;
```

As Duncan points out, arrayByAddingObjects doesn't make sense there. [NSMutableArray init] shouldn't even compile: ALWAYS fix your warnings, they almost always indicate an error in your code.

Consider also: If self.model.selectedLetters is nil, the problem might be that self.model is nil, not that model.selectedLetters is nil!

Comment: So when touchesBegan is called in my SKLetterNode, and if I want to correctly use the MVC pattern, would the best option for my SKLetterNode to communicate with my model be to set up a delegate and just have my SKLetterNode communicate with my SKScene, and then have the SKSCene communicate with the modal? I'm also just now reading about protocols and it seems like that might be an option as well.